# Is it important to keep my pastebin developer key private?

Tags: http, key-management

I would like for my application to enable users to save their programs to Pastebin through the [Pastebin api](http://pastebin.com/api).  This requires a developer key, which is automatically created with each account.  Keeping the developer key secret would be an inconvenience, both because my project is open source and because the most natural place to submit data to Pastebin from is the browser client, from which it would be easy for a user to intercept it.

Someone who misused my developer key would not be able to delete or (worse) modify users' pastes.  The worst outcome I can think of is that a malicious user would spam Pastebin, and I'd have to get a new account and key, but is there a more serious outcome that I need to protect against?

Comment: ....so that's a yes, then?

Comment: You're implying that having to get a new account is a big deal?  My thinking was that I could go through the effort of developing a secure solution only if someone steals and abuses the developer key.  They're as difficult to get as hotmail addresses, so I'm hoping it won't be a problem.

Comment: If someone wanted to cause grief for you, he could write a script that finds the new key as soon as you put it into your project and get it banned again within minutes.  This could be quite an inconvenience.

Comment: Worst case is I'd have to write the secure code then, which could be a problem if I had a public launch.

Answer (score 3):

When you host the app yourself, you obviously use your own developer key.

But don't ship your developer API key in your source code; have people who download and run your code use their own.

That page you linked states clearly that all Pastebin users get a developer API key.

> Everybody using our API is required to use a valid Developer API Key. You automatically get a key when you become a member of Pastebin. Please login to your account, and return to this page to find your Developer API Key.

Comment: I wasn't planning to make my users create Pastebin accounts.  They'll be running off my server, not creating their own.

Comment: If you're _hosting_ the app, then sure, use your own developer key. But there's no good reason to put _your_ key on github. If someone wants to fork you, they can get their own key.

Comment: That's a good point about forking.  I hadn't thought of that.  Someone could still get the key from the browser, but they'd have to be malicious, rather than passive.

Comment: I can also store the key in a .gitignore'd file.